# How to debug caching of Rmarkdown chunk evaluation?

Tags: r, debugging, caching, knitr, r-markdown

I have an [Rmarkdown file](https://github.com/DarwinAwardWinner/CD4-csaw/blob/master/scripts/rnaseq-explore.Rmd) for which I'm trying to enable caching. When I render it to HTML, it does indeed cache the results of each chunk. However, on subsequent runs, it seems to always ignore the cache and re-run every chunk. Presumably some variable is changing on every run, resulting in every cached result being invalidated, but I have no idea what it might be. Is there any way I can have knitr tell me why it decides to invalidate a cache and re-run a cached chunk, so I can debug the situation?

Comment: what do you have in your `params` parameters given to `cache.extra` ? I can't see where they are defined

Comment: The params are defined in the YAML header, as described here: http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/developer_parameterized_reports.html. I'm running this same Rmarkdown file on several data sets. The value of the params should always be identical every time I run it on the same data set.